# connect MySQL database with play-framework 2.5

Tags: java, mysql, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I am **trying to connect MySQL database with Play-framework- Java** **2.5.4**.

I am getting this **error**,

```
either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required
```

These are the connection codes that I am using inside ***App.conf*** file,

```
db {
  db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playdb"
  db.default.user="root"
  db.default.password="9413678957"
}
```

But its giving me following errors while connecting :

```
caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:785)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:141)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:57)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
```

When I am connecting to mysql database **with same**(same as in App.conf)

- url (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playdb)
- username
- password

Using **Intellij**, **its working fine**.

Please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have an error in other place, check your dataSource config. Like this: ` db.default.datasource="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"`

Comment: where to write this, u mean in app.conf

Comment: @BaBL86 thanks, should I include it inside application.conf file

Comment: try adding `db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"` to application.conf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Finally this worked for me :-**

**This error killed my lot of time.**

Here is what worked for me,

uncomment these line.

```
    play.db {
             config = "db"
             default = "default" 
    }
```

then

```
    db {

  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playdb"
  default.username=root
  default.password="9403678957"
}
```

**don't need`db.default.*`, as you already in the db set range.**

Lots of thanks to this [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/aL_uFk70je0/1qpnzHY0AgAJ).

Answer (score 0):

You must not specify db in the path, you are already in the db section of the config

so:
**db.**default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
should be just:
default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
db {
  default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playdb"
  default.user="root"
  default.password="9413678957"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check this example repo https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

You can also see the tutorial I did at http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

while both aim to play 2.4.x you should be able to understand what's the error you are having. Still, there's also a PR to upgrade to play 2.5.x at https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps/pull/2

Comment: got these error  by adding ## mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.34

to build.sbt ##

####errors start ###





Error injecting method, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.api.PlayConfig.getOptional(Ljava/lang/String;Lplay/api/ConfigLoader;)Lscala/Option;
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.java:40):


####errors end ###

Comment: Have you looked into the pr i mentioned?